# SSD only booting when connected with USB, not with SATA

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, ssd, sata

I'm trying to connect a SSD to my Windows 10 IoT device via SATA but when I try to boot I get a BSOD during startup saying ***Incompatible boot device***. One or two times I also got the error saying that the file ***\Windows\System32\winload.exe*** is missing or contains errors. I checked the data on the SSD and the file is present.

Now the strange thing. When connect the SSD to a SATA to USB adapter and boot from there, it works without any hassle. It starts up normally and I can do anything I want with it.

I wanted to test if there was something wrong with the SSD, so I copied another image over to it and connected it via SATA, and it **can** boot from it without problems. I then tried to boot with the image that was on another SSD (not the same as the copied one), and it **couldn't** boot from SATA.

Does someone know what might cause this problem? Eventually I need to boot from that first SSD with the image I started with on it (and it needs to be connected via SATA).

***UPDATE:*** The problem is fixed, it has nothing to do with hardware or firmware, but everything with software (a.k.a. Windows being stupid). I booted it via USB and could activate ***safe boot***. I connected the SSD via SATA and it managed to boot in safe mode. Then I simply deactivated it and it booted successfully in normal mode.

Comment: Investigate against [this issue](https://superuser.com/a/985330/432690).

Comment: SSD1 is only 120GB, SSD2 is only 100GB. With the image I'm trying to boot, only about 16GB of the 120GB is in use (the rest is unallocated).

Comment: Try other SATA ports on your motherboard. The windows bootloader will try to connect to the partition directly based on what SATA port its connected to. It may also cause problems if more than one HDD is attached, and your SSD's C drive gets a different driveletter. Windows is no longer found at C:\.

Comment: @LPChip I only have one SATA port. I'm using custom hardware.

Comment: found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1073193/hdd-not-booting-over-sata-only-over-usb?rq=1) issue

Comment: just use a usb stick to boot, don't waste a SSD

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I need [UWF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/unified-write-filter), and it doesn't work with a usb stick